# my browser don't show any picture?

Tags: html

I have attached an image to my asp page but my browsers(IE and Firefox) doesn't show it!!!the picture is from my own computer.where is the problem?

```
<img  alt="picture" src="file:///C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample20Pictures/Tulips.jpg"  style="margin-bottom: 0px; width: 100px; height: 100px; margin-left: 5px;"  />
```

thanks for your helps!!

Comment: I would recommend reading this first to improve your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your src path "file:///", it looks like it has one slash to many. Please change it to "file://C....." and check again.

Also have a look at the following page in case you try to link a local image from a remote HTML page (not sure if that's the case in your scenario):
[Linking a UNC / Network drive on an html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369147/linking-a-unc-network-drive-on-an-html-page)

Comment: Hardly too many slashes, more like too few. Click through to the linked answer.

Comment: thank you, but it doesn't work again.....if I type this path"file:///c...."directly in firefox address bar it shows me the picture but in the code it doesn't work....plz help me!