# Possible to use Virtual Path to an external disk on Plesk Managed Windows server?

Tags: iis, plesk, windows-server

After getting a helpful answer from this post [I want to store media on a separate harddrive on the windows server. Is it possible to make those files available via http?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26805676/i-want-to-store-media-on-a-separate-harddrive-on-the-windows-server-is-it-possi)

I soon discovered that Plesk does not allow me to create a virtual path that points to a location outside of my website root. I want the virtual path to point to a folder on D: (an extra disk, not the same as the website root directory)

Only two possible solutions I could think of, although I can't find them any where.

1) Maybe plesk has an advanced configuration file that prevents it from overwriting certain things in IIS when it runs its maintenance jobs or updates, specifically the Virtual Path I created directly in IIS outside of plesk.

2) Maybe there is a third party component available that offers this functionality, setting virtual paths outside of web root or the config file I just mentioned in #1.

Any other solutions are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd "%plesk_vhosts%\"domain.tld\httpdocs
mklink /J point c:\outOfSpace
```

Now provide permissions to "psacln" group to c:\outOfSpace and that's it.

Also you can create "point" not in httpdocs but in web space root and than from Plesk create Virtual Folder inside /httpdocs with needed access permissions.

There is issue that your custom permissions may lost after Plesk upgrade, this KB article describe how your can avoid it [kb.sp.parallels.com/111194](http://kb.sp.parallels.com/111194)

Comment: Maybe I need to edit my question to clarify. Will this allow a user to go to mywebsite.com/virtualdirectory and grab a file at D:/OtherDiskFolder/somefile.jpg ?