# How to create a (cross browser compatible) hyperlink that opens a file on a network drive?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, cross-browser

I want to open Documents from Shared Folder on network using ASP.NET with C#.
My situation as follow:

1. My Web Server Name is “WebServer1” use IIS 7
2. My DC Server Name is “DC1”
3. My File Server Name “FileServer1”
4. My Files Path
   `\\FileServer1\A\B\C\MyDoc.docx` and `\\FileServer1\A\B\C\MyPDF.pdf`

I tried the following

**1-    I Created Hyper Link**

```
<a href="file:///// FileServer1\A\B\C\MyDoc.docx" target="_blank">link to file</a>
```

The files open on some machines that uses Internet Explorer version 8 but on any other version or Chrome, Fire Fox, or any other web browser it doesn't work when I click on the hyper link no action happens and no errors, but if I copied the link address and pasted it into the web browser the file opens

I gave the path in the file server full control permission for “everyone”

**2-    I also tried to create a button with the following code**

```
Response.ContentType = 
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats- officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=5401-1-2289.docx");
Response.Redirect("file:///// FileServer1\A\B\C\MyDoc.docx");
Response.Flush();
```

Comment: The `file:///// ` contains a space after the last `/`, is this correct?

Comment: When using `Content-Disposition: attachment`, you need to write the file to output, not use a `Redirect`. You can use something like `Response.TransmitFile(@"\\FileServer1\A\B\C\MyDoc.docx");` As for the hyperlink/redirect, it would require the user to have access to the shared drive, not the web server. And it only ever works in Outlook / IE / Word etc., by design - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369147/linking-a-unc-network-drive-on-an-html-page

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the URL is incorrect. It should be `@"file://\\FileServer1\A\B\C\MyDoc.docx"` instead of `"file:///// FileServer1\A\B\C\MyDoc.docx"` (I have a hard time thinking this actually compiles, because you didn't escape `\`...)

Second, you are combining both sending content, as redirecting, as [pointed out by Luaan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30047095/hyperlink-to-network-drive-files-is-not-working-asp-net-with-c-sharp#comment48209502_30047095) in a comment. This won't work.

You could transmit the file directly. This also prevents you to expose your network drive to external users:

```
Response.TransmitFile(@"\\FileServer1\A\B\C\MyDoc.docx");
```

Comment: Actually, `file://///` is the correct prefix - that's the IE convention. But that's still the point - it's only an IE convention, and it only really existed for ActiveDesktop and similar stuff (it's deprecated in IE 9). For security reasons, this isn't supported by browsers anymore.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks for pointing that out. Still it is very IE specific and shouldn't be used, so I will keep it in the post. And it shouldn't compile...