# How to put a hyperlink for local server location on a webpage?

Tags: html, wordpress

I have to put a local server location's link on a wordpress blog page.

The location is of the nature //192.168.20.68/localfolder/

I've tried putting file:///localhost/192.168.20.68/localfolder

```
<a href="file://192.168.20.68/localfolder" target="_blank">Local Folder</a>
```

or

```
<a href="file://192.168.20.68/localfolder" onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;" onkeypress="window.open(this.href); return false;">This link will open in new window/tab</a>
```

It opens a new tab, but doesn't open any link. Its just blank.
Can someone kindly help?

Comment: When you manually go to the location in a browser, what does the address bar say?

Comment: If I manually enter the location 'file://192.168.20.68/localfolder/'  in the browser, it open the list of files on the server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linking a UNC / Network drive on an html page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369147/linking-a-unc-network-drive-on-an-html-page)