# Backslashes are getting removed from string

Tags: javascript

Javascript removes back slashes from string.

```js
var a='https:\\abc\qwe.com';
console.log(a);
var b=encodeURI(a);
console.log(b);
var c='https:\\\abc\\qwe.com';
console.log(c);
var d='https:\\\\abc\\qwe.com';
console.log(d);
```

Is there any way to get Javascript to not remove the backslashes in the `console.log` input strings?

Comment: yes, use actual slashes instead of backslashes.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: why use backslash in url ?

Comment: in my case url is pointing to some machine address, so it needs backslash in url

Comment: No you don't. It's either an URI or an UNC path, you can't combine them like that. If you want to create a clickable link/URI, you want to have a `file://` url with slashes instead of backslashes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369147/linking-a-unc-network-drive-on-an-html-page

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript (and other languages) the backslash `\` is used as an escape character, f.e. to be able to get a double quote in your string: `"\""`. (Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) under Escape notation)

The side effect is that, if you want a backslash in your string, you need a double backslash: `"\\"` results in `\`.

This said, URL's use slashes instead of backslashes: "https://abc/qwe"

If you're looking for URL encoding, use the [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) or [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function.

Answer (score 0):

You are using backslashes, not slashes(`/`). They are used to escape special symbols (and the backslash itself). You do not need them to write URLs, actually.