# Drupal WYSIWYG strips file:/// protocol in CKEDITOR

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, ckeditor, wysiwyg, ckeditor4.x

Drupal HTML **WYSIWY Filter** strips "**file:///**" from hyperlinks even though I have allowed the HTML attribute a[*], what am I missing?

I want to open a **local path** \myserver\folder\file and thus I added the protocol in the **link dialogue** and can see in the plain text editor that the href is created properly:

```
<a href="file:///\\myserver\folder\file" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">test</a>
```

but when I preview/save it that gets stripped and thus is not working

```
<a href="///\\myserver\folder\file" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">test</a>
```

Comment: I managed to make file protocol work via filter protocol module (see below answer) but only works in IE and only reaches the server path without spaces while %20 doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

[Filter Protocol](https://www.drupal.org/project/filter_protocols) module allows adding them, however, I discovered that the [file URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) (file:\ protocol) to open remote server location is **not supported** on most browsers for *security* reasons [Linking a UNC / Network drive on an html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369147/linking-a-unc-network-drive-on-an-html-page)

Unfortunately adding a browser extension isn't always a practical workaround.